# Are session variables in shared memory?

Tags: php, session, shared-memory

If you are familiar with programing languages like VB.NET, you know there is something name Shared-Memory which is shared between different instance of application. My question is :Are session variables behave the same in PHP or not?

---

Assume this scenario:

I click twice on a link in my web-site (Both requests are sent with same headers, same cookies but in different times). `$_SESSION['num']` is set to `0` and now:

On 12:00:00.01 first request is received by the server
On 12:00:00.03 first request starts its session
On 12:00:00.04 second request is received by the server
On 12:00:00.05 second request starts its session.
On 12:00:00.06 first process adds `10` to value of `$_SESSION['num']`.
On 12:00:00.07 second process adds `10` to value of `$_SESSION['num']`.
On 12:00:00.09 both processes are finished.

Now , there are two possible answers:`$_SESSION['num']` is `10` or `$_SESSION['num']` is 20. Which one is the answer?

Comment: Quick answer: no. As for your example, that entirely depends on if each request shares the same session

Comment: @Phil I said I **clicked twice on a link**, which means they both use the same session!

Comment: Ah, my apologies. "click" is such a nebulous term. Without further information such as which browser, tab, etc was used, I didn't want to jump to conclusions. The answer then would be 20.

Comment: @Phil I mean both requests are the exact same, the only difference here would be the time that session starts!

Comment: You seem to have some confusion about what a *session* is. I suggest you start here - http://php.net/manual/intro.session.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual answer to your uestion is "what happened when you tested it?"

PHP will store your sessions [wherever you tell it to](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) store the sessions: files, shared memory, a database. By default it uses files. The session is retrieved from storage when you call session_start() it is written back to storage when you call session_write_close(), or the script exits.

If your session handler acquires a lock on the storage, then the second instance will be blocked until the first instance writes back the changes. The default files handler [acquires locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371474/php-sessions-is-there-any-way-to-disable-php-session-locking).

Comment: I couldn't test it because I couldn't send simultaneous requests! But thanks!

Comment: Why not? (hint: have a look at the sleep() function).

Comment: I tried that, but it seems browsers don't send simultaneous requests. They wait for first request to be done and then start the other one!

Comment: Most browsers *do* send simultaeneous requests. Try opening a new window/tab (should inherit the session cookies) or simply create a HTML page with 2 iframes.