# Is there some kind of performance (or other) punishment for using session_start() but not really using the session super-array?

Tags: php, performance, session

I've always wondered why PHP makes you manually `session_start()` in order to gain access to the immensely useful `$_SESSION` "super-array".

It strikes me that this might be causing a lot of stress on the server, but not really make a difference in practice unless you have an extreme amount of users.

I don't really see why it would cause such a strain, though, if you don't use that array/mechanism. And if you do, you always want `session_start()` to have been called... It would really be nice to finally get this straightened out.

The manual doesn't offer any explanation: https://www.php.net/session_start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a question of *how much overhead* it causes, as far as why sessions aren't started by default. There are tons of possible PHP applications that have nothing to do with session variables (including any CLI use!), and therefore, on principle it shouldn't be automatically started. Establishing an idle database connection ("immensely useful!") also doesn't create silly overhead. It's still not done by default. Resources should be available, but uninstantiated.

The main performance impact caused by starting a session, with or without ever using it, basically involves (quoting from the manual on [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/session_start)):

- PHP will call the open and read session save handlers. ... The read callback will retrieve any existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back to PHP session handling.

This typically means disk access to look up and read the serialized session data. Even if it's empty or non-existent. (It will not be created until `$_SESSION` variables are used; but you won't know if it's there without trying!) Also: *your session ID is typically stored in a cookie*. Want session? Make a cookie, take a cookie, pass a cookie, read a cookie, etc. pass/read on each page load. Unnecessary baking and trading, and we'd rather avoid redundant HTTP traffic.

Aside that, there's a strange and wonderful thing called [session locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371474/php-sessions-is-there-any-way-to-disable-php-session-locking) that can make you scractczch your head a lot and wonder why you can't load long-running scripts on your site in two tabs simultaneously, even when you've double-damned-configured your Apache, MySQL and the rest to handle concurrent connections and/or space alien armadas on steroids. Without session locking, you could. (Alas, debugging long-running scripts with sessions on!)

Significantly, this will haunt you with concurrent AJAX requests to PHP scripts with sessions; they'll be sequentially processed instead. There are ways to overcome session locking delays, but the default behavior blocks parallel execution, and requests are queued, and it's rather annoying but a necessary evil to prevent race conditions and session corruption ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371474/php-sessions-is-there-any-way-to-disable-php-session-locking)).

So much for the obvious performance/quirks side. In terms of customizing how things work, there are functions that may be called before `session_start()`, such as `session_name()` (for named sessions). The session_start function itself (as of PHP 7) takes an optional array of [session parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) which you couldn't use, were the session started by default.

If you look at the link above, you'll notice that there *is* in fact a session auto-start option in `php.ini` session configuration:

> **session.auto_start** boolean
>
> session.auto_start specifies whether the session module starts a session automatically on request startup. Defaults to 0 (disabled).

There are some related cautions in [PHP Intro to Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) on the `auto_start` option:

> **Caution** If you turn on session.auto_start then the only way to put objects into your sessions is to load its class definition using auto_prepend_file in which you load the class definition else you will have to serialize() your object and unserialize() it afterwards.

If you are certain that you always want to use sessions, the simplest move would be to create a bootup file that you require at the beginning of files that use sessions; add the path to the file into your include path; and then simply `<?php require 'sessions.php'` before your main code begins.

The session bootup file could also have some of your own session-handling functions, etc. relevant standard material. This route would give you more freedom than the auto-start option, plus a way to implement other options and functionality across all your session-using code. *You shouldn't rely on the auto-start in any case, in case you ever want to create code that can be easily deployed into environments with default PHP configuration!*

Comment: Great answer, but I have two quibbles: 1. Cookies are simple HTTP request/response headers, but your answer makes it seem like there is additional negotiation overhead passing them back and forth when there is virtually none. 2. I would default to _always_ starting a session, and for requests where you know you won't need it, or no longer need it after a certain point, there is [`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to free up the session for parallel requests.

Comment: 1. Yes that's correct, there are no additional HTTP requests made. Regardless, avoiding unnecessary cookies is a [recommended practice](https://www.globaldots.com/blog/googles-web-performance-best-practices-3-minimize-request-overhead) to minimize HTTP overhead. 2. That'd be the default way to deal with it. My session-related bootup logic allows scripts to request no-session, full-session, or read-only session (`session_start(['read_and_close' => true]`, leaving the `$_SESSION` readable). 3. I've expanded on the **session locking** issue, which commonly haunts AJAX requests.